# Как правильно разместить блок ниже абсолютно позиционированного

Tags: css, вёрстка, html, position

Здравствуйте, есть 3 блока, Блок2 должен немного наезжать на первый и перекрывать его,тут проблем не возникло, сделал с помощью position:absolute, но вот блок 3 перекрывается блоком 2, который задан абсолютным, можно было бы конечно задать margin, чтобы избежать этого но при изменении размеров экрана все ломается. В общем смысл в том, чтобы Блок3 был расположен ниже блока 2 и не перекрывался ним даже при изменении размеров экрана. Может подскажете какой-нибудь способ? Заранее спасибо

```css
div{
width:300px;
height:200px;
}
.block1{
background-color:green;
}
.block2{
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
}
.block3{
background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">Block1</div>
<div class="block2">Block2</div>
<div class="block3">Block3</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понял, а что конкретно ломается?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .9);
  width: 330px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">Block1</div>
<div class="block2">Block2</div>
<div class="block3">Block3</div>
```

Еще варинант

```css
:root {
  --offset: -100px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .9);
  width: 330px;
  transform: translateY(var(--offset));
}

.block3 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 360px;
  transform: translateY(var(--offset));
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">Block1</div>
<div class="block2">Block2</div>
<div class="block3">Block3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

например 3-ему блоку задать `position: relative` и необходимый `top`:

```css
div{
width:300px;
height:200px;
}
.block1{
background-color:green;
}
.block2{
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
}
.block3{
background-color:orange;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">Block1</div>
<div class="block2">Block2</div>
<div class="block3">Block3</div>
```